# databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.details.GeoDetails>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I want to make a call to an external API using Springboot.

This is the json format i want to receive:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "address": {
            "street": "Kulas Light",
            "suite": "Apt. 556",
            "city": "Gwenborough",
            "zipcode": "92998-3874",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-37.3159",
                "lng": "81.1496"
            }
        },
        "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
        "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
            "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
            "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
        }
    }
```

**UserModel.java**

```
    package com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.model;

import com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.details.AddressDetails;
import com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.details.CompanyDetails;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@Data

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserModel implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String username;

    private String email;

    private AddressDetails address;

    private String phone;

    private String website;

    private CompanyDetails company;

}
```

**AddressDetails.java**

```
package com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.details;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Data

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AddressDetails {

    private String street;

    private String suite;

    private String city;

    private String zipcode;

    private List<GeoDetails> geo;
```

**CompanyDetails.java**

```
package com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.details;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Data

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CompanyDetails {

    private String name;

    private String catchPhrase;

    private String bs;
}
```

**GeoDetails.java**

```
package com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.details;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Data

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GeoDetails {

    private String lat;
    private String lng;
}
```

**UserService**

```
package com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.service;

import com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.model.UserModel;

public interface UserService {

    public UserModel[] getAllUsers();
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.service;


import com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.model.UserModel;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Value("${external.api.url}")
    private String userApiBaseUrl;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public UserModel[] getAllUsers() {


        UserModel[]  result = restTemplate.getForObject(userApiBaseUrl+"/users", UserModel[].class);

        System.out.println(result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

**UserController**

```
package com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.controller;

import com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.model.UserModel;
import com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public UserModel[] getAllUsers(){
        UserModel[] response =userService.getAllUsers();
        return response;
    }

}
```

***i get this error:***

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.details.GeoDetails>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 12, column: 14] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0]->com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.model.UserModel["address"]->com.example.SpringBootExternalAPI.details.AddressDetails["geo"])
```

I don't know if i need to fix the UserModel class or i need to add something else in my code.

Comment: In your `AddressDetails` you have the field `List<GeoDetails> geo`. In your JSON just a single object. That explains the mentioned error message. Jackson is looking for an array but getting an object.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was such a silly mistake and i didh't notice that!